# Update texture with three.js

Tags: three.js, textures

I've got a textured model in three.js and I want to be able to swap out the texture defined in the .gltf file when the page loads. I've looked [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things) for inspiration.

```
"images": [
{
  "uri": "flat_baseColor.png"
},
// etc
```

So to update the texture I do

```
var images = [
"./textures/01.jpg",
//  "./textures/01.jpg",
];


var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( images[0] );

var my_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});

// load the model
var loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/gltf/' ); // trex
loader.load( 'creature_posed.gltf', function ( gltf ) 
{
    gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child )
    {
        if ( child.isMesh )
        {
            // The textures go for a double flip, I have no idea why
            // Texture compensation
            texture.flipX = false;
            texture.flipY = false;
            child.material = my_material;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        }
    } );


    var model = gltf.scene;
```

Only the texture is considerably pale. :(
[image: texture ob model before and after update]

I've tested it against itself, so it's not the texture). What have a missed out?

Comment: You change the original material, which is affected by light (could be `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()`), with `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()`, which is not affected by light.

Comment: @prisoner849 good call, but now also confused. I used `var my_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});` as the original material

Comment: Is the original texture the right colours? Have you tried these settings on the renderer - `renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;` and `renderer.gammaOutput = true;`

Comment: May also want `texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding`; see https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy That was it! Feel free to write that up as an answer if you want :)

Comment: @danlong Those two lines didn't fix it, but they can't hurt either. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loading textures you'll need to pay attention to colorspace: if the texture has color data (like `.map` or `.emissiveMap`) it's probably sRGB.

```js
texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

See [GLTFLoader docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) and [color management in three.js](https://gist.github.com/donmccurdy/fefb35c5ba033e7dcd641f9684e47a82). This assumes that `renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding` as well.

three.js r113