# Updated textures stops animation in three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, textures

Moving on from [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302943/update-texture-with-three-js). I'm swapping out a texture on a .GLTF on page refresh. The texture now works fine and dandy...

But only on files that have no animation. The texture update however, seems to stop them in their literal tracks. I've not sure what's causing it or how to reload the animations.

Here's the code:

```
    var creaturePath = "models/gltf/creature/";
    var creatureFile = "creature_roar.gltf";

    // load the model
    var loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( creaturePath ); // creature

    loader.load( creatureFile, function ( gltf ) 
    {
        gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child )
        {
            if ( child.isMesh )
            {
                // override textures
                texture.flipX = false;
                texture.flipY = false;
                my_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
                // child.material = my_material; // this is the problem line
                texture.needsUpdate = true;
            }

        } );

        var model = gltf.scene;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replace the material, you have to ensure to set [MeshBasicMaterial.skinning](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.skinning) and/or [MeshBasicMaterial.morphTargets](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.morphTargets) to `true`. Otherwise skeletal and/or morph target animation won't be supported by the material.

`three.js R113`

Comment: I've tried 'skinning: true;
child.MeshBasicMaterial.skinning = true;
my_material.MeshBasicMaterial.skinning = true;` to no effect. Can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: It should be `my_material.skinning = true;` and/or `my_material.morphTargets = true;`.

Comment: Fifth time's the charm! Thank you.

Comment: @Mugen87 It worked, but do you know which attribute should I set if the material is ShaderMaterial?

Comment: `ShaderMaterial` does not automatically support animations. You have to add the respective shader chunks first.